# I need to .htaccess redirect my subfolder to the root folder, except two folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The subfolder i want to redirect to the root folder is [www.example.com/subfolder](http://www.example.com/subfolder)

So I need to redirect everything in that subfolder to the url adress https://www.example.com except for these two folders (which are placed in the subfolder): [www.example.com/subfolder/folder1](http://www.example.com/subfolder/folder1) and [www.example.com/subfolder/folder2](http://www.example.com/subfolder/folder2)

I spent like 4 hours trying to find the exact code but I could not solve that. Nothing worked for me.

I've tried many codes, but nothing worked for me. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/subfolder/folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/subfolder/folder2/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on  
Options +FollowSymlinks 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/subfolder/folder1/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/subfolder/folder2/ 
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/subfolder/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule    (.*)  https://www.example.com     [R]
```

Could someone help me with that?

I'd prefer to place the .htaccess file in the subfolder.

Thank you so much.

Comment: So what is your actual question, what is the issue you face why you can't implement this yourself? please note that SO is _not_ a free coding service. We are here to help you solve your issues, we are not here to do your work for you. So please go, learn the basics, start yourself and implement a solution. _Then_ , if you have an issue you cannot solve yourself, _then_ is the time to come here and ask. And to include your best attempt and a precise explanation what behaves different to what you would expect.

Comment: I spent like 4 hours trying to find this exact code but I could not solve that. Nothing worked for me. I really tried my best.

Comment: I posted a slighty altered variant of your first attempt. If that does not work, then you need to explain what "does not work" actually means, _exactly_ . So what happens if you make a test request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your first attempt looks pretty good. Just make a slight modification since you say you want to redirect to the root path, not something inside the root path:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/subfolder/folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/subfolder/folder2/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Since you want to use a distributed configuration file (as opposed to the preferred central configuration for the http host) that rule is meant to be used inside a ".htaccess" file inside the "subfolder".

It is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as intended. Also you need to make sure that you always test using a fresh anonymous browser window to prevent client side caching effects.

And you also need to make sure that such distributed configuration files are considered at all by the http server for that location (see the documentation of the `AllowOverride` directive).